# Problem with GPS porting

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, notifications

I'm working on a GPS porting project where we need to avoid all the framework changes. This was acheived through a socket where an application (GPS Settings) talks to GPS library (Middleware) and vice versa.

**Issues**

1. In GUI, Socket is running in one
   thread and not able to call methods
   in the main thread
   activity(securitySetting.java). For
   this we are using the Handler to
   communicate with the main thread but
   the problem still persists. The
   problem here is the actual source is
   modifed, securitysettings is
   inherited from
   "SettingsPreferenceFragment" where
   when i check the actual source it is
   inherited from preferenceactivity.
   Every time i am using
   securitysettings.this.getactivity()
   to get the context.
2. Need to show few notifications,
   after completion of work in GPS
   library. Its is not possible from
   security settings activity as it
   can't be avaialble all the time.
   Please suggest if any work around to
   show the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding this question.

To me it sounds like a threading/UI issue. You have a separate thread running, doing some work and you want the Activity on the UI Thread to get notified when this background thread is done, so it can display something to the user. Is that correct?